# Alarm not sounding on an Honor 6X

Tags: huawei, alarm

Note: I have researched this online, but none of the answers seem to work.

Currently, my honor 6X does not make any alarm sound. Obviously, this can lead to some predictable problems. I've made sure of the following:

1. My volume, ringer, alarm, and calls are all turned to max.
2. My regular volume works perfectly
3. I am using the default clock app
4. I deleted all my alarms and tried again, to no avail
5. My phone was restarted (I do not want to do a factory restart unless that is the only possible solution)
6. The alarm pops up, but has no sound
7. I gave clock priority over other apps and gave it all the permissions possible
8. I've tried different alarm sounds and reset it to the default
9. I have turned off Bluetooth
10. I have cleared all other apps
11. I have turned off the Android given task manager
12. I have no other clock apps
13. Although, my phone *is* rooted, but for over a year now, and have only encountered this problem very recently, so I think I can cross that off my list.

I am completely lost now on what to do, I have basically tried everything possible. So how in the world can I get this to work? Any opinion or idea would be greatly appreciated

Comment: In alarm settings, please check whether you have enabled gradually increase volume to never. ( I am using Google clock)

Comment: Have you disallowed notifications for the Clock app (including disallowing sound there)?

Comment: Also check if it is a protected app or whatever it is called now for those apps that switch off after screen is off

Comment: @wbogacz nope, all permissions granted

Comment: @beeshyams I completely turned off the "protection app" for all apps.

Comment: @Rahul Gopi I can't seem to find that setting in my clock settings

Comment: this image shows settings for timer which is similar to that of alarm. https://i2.wp.com/mashtips.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/AddClock_Timer.jpeg?resize=600%2C320&ssl=1

Answer (score 1):

you can also try the following two methods.

1. In the **Settings - Smart Assist - Gesture setting**, there is an alarm to turn the mute to see if it is caused by flipping the phone and causing the alarm to be muted.
2. Wait for the new version and upgrade to the latest version